# Какое убожество! Дно!

Tags: синтаксис, синтаксический-разбор

"Какое убожество!" — бытийно-оценочное предложение, а "Дно!" — постпозитивный номинатив?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Какое убожество! Дно!***

При анализе подобных конструкций сложно дать однозначный ответ,  так как и в теории нет однозначности. Поэтому нужно ориентироваться **на определения.**

Оценочные конструкции относят к постпозитивным номинативам или к номинативным предложения. Где критерий?

**Для номинативов** важно то, что они несамостоятельны и тесно связаны с предыдущим **текстом**. **Номинативные оценочные предложения** — это **реакция наблюдателя** на предмет или явление.

Если приведенный пример — это **реакция** наблюдателя, то первое предложение является **бытийно-оценочным**.

Хотя второе предложение уже связано с предыдущим текстом, но оно **синонимично** ему, это та же реакция, выраженная другим словом.

Поэтому я думаю, что **оба предложения являются бытийно-оценочными**.

Материал по теме:

https://studfiles.net/preview/2682296/

https://studfiles.net/preview/3488542/page:2/